# upload file outside of root folder

Tags: php

```
public_html/(root)index.php
           /image/123.jpg
           /subdomain(root)/upload.php
```

I have file upload.php can upload image, this file is locate in sub-domain folder (I have set sub-domain folder as another root)

I need to upload image to main domain, `/image/` (image's folder)

however I could not find the right path. I have try `../` but it wont work above the root

anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably the webserver don't have permission to write the above directories. Anyway you should find first the errors to resolve them. What is in the error logs? Or do you have other errors maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use path like /home/content/html/images